# features of these keyboard symbols "/" and "\"

Tags: keyboard

Please explain me the **features** of these two symbols "**/**" and "**\**". Also,

1. **How are these two symbols different?**
2. **Use of these two symbols**
3. **Does these two symbols have different behaviors in windows and linux?**

Thank You!!!

Comment: They're two different characters, just like A and B.  On a computer command line there are significant differences in how the characters are treated/used in DOS/Windows vs Unix/Linux, but in a plain old editor, editing a letter, eg, they are just characters that you can use however you want.

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard themselves mean nothing. Its what you *do* with them that's important.

There's nothing stopping you from using emoji cat pictures on a custom keyboard you designed with a sharpie to do the same thing.

The [backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash) is *very* often an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). It tells a parser or a compiler that the following symbol should be interpreted *differently*. For example, you'd use `\n` as a newline and you'd often also use a backslash to tell your system to interpret something *literally*. Imagine you had a language where you had to encase a string in double quotes for example.

`print " "quoty thing""` would be parsed as, well,  -  since your language assumes the string is encapsulated inside the *first* pair of quotation marks

While there's other clever ways to do it (mixing single and double quotes), if you needed a double quote inside there you'd go `print " \"quotey thing\""` to print "quotey thing" else it would parse.

There's very little reason to use a backslash slash in english, so as a modifier, its simple and non confusing... And there's no real sense in using it for directory seperatoes.

And.... Windows does it anyway. Oh well. No one's perfect.

The *forward* slash on the other hand is the swiss army knife of seperators on unixy systems. Want to seperate directories in a path? Use a forward slash. Want to seperate parts of a URL? Yup, forward slash. Its also sometimes used as a division operator (for obvious reasons), or in a pair for oneline comments (and as part of the `/*` `*/` comment block). Its also used in HTML (and many other markup tag languages). In fact, there's so many possible uses, I'll point you at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slash_%28punctuation%29#Computing) for a full list.

Comment: @Journeyman Geek
Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The "\" (backslash) and the "/" (slash or forward slash) are basically the same, except different OS's use them differently.

The "\" is used by windows to show levels, e.g. `C:\Users\User\My Pictures`
The "/" is used by Unix (Mac OS X and Linux, generally) to show levels, e.g. `/Users/user/Pictures`
The "/" is also used in internet URLs in a similar way, e.g. `www.google.com/chrome`

As far as I know, no mainstream OS uses both "/" and "\" but one or the other. I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

1. yes they are different. / is forward slash and \ is backslash.
2. in operating systems they are often used as separators in file systems.  There may also other uses.
3. Windows uses a backslash (\) as the separator in file paths.  Linux uses the forward slash (/) as the separator in file paths.